# Configure endpoints for Facebook Realtime Updates in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to implement Realtime Updates for my Facebook MVC application. I created it from template in Visual Studio. 
I'm following [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) and [this blog post](http://trocolate.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/realtime-update-in-asp-net-mvc-facebook-template/).

Template has already some boilerplate code for `UserRealtimeUpdateController`. How to configure endpoints to listen to subscriptions, and what should I put as my callback, when I create new Realtime Update Subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints are defined in `WebApiConfig` class in `App_Start` folder.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

So, by default the callback URL should be something like:

```
http://yourservername.com/api/userrealtimeupdate
```